# Is it possible to create instances of all classes in an assembly?

Tags: c#, dll

I have an application which creates and exports a `.dll` which contains custom icons for WPF forms.

I'm trying to create a sort of exploratory test where I can open up an app, and choose a `.dll`. Once I have chosen the `.dll` it will look inside of it and create instances of each class in there, and then add these objects to the form.

I want to be able to do this as a quick test to see that all the icons in that `.dll` display correctly before sending it out to a customer.

I am able to get all of the types inside of the `.dll` by:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileDialog.FileName);

foreach (var type in assembly.DefinedTypes)
{
   Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow use this to create the objects.

Comment: How does those icons are stored in the dll? as resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution will be using .NET  Activator class. It is using reflection but since you want create this object for testing purposes I don't think that overhead will make difference for you.
You can use Activator like this:

```
Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

If you need to create object which constructor needs some parameter you can call overloaded CreateInstance which accepts arguments:

```
Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstace(type, new object[] {"arg1", "arg2"});
```

CreateInstance method will return object but you can always cast to desired type (if you know it) so you can easily perform some operations on newly created object. Alternatively you can call methods, set properties using reflection.

You can read more about Activator on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you aren't really interested in creating all the types, you want to create types that implement a certain interface or that subclass a certain class:

```
Type baseType = typeof(... someting ...);
Assembly assembly = ... your assembly ...;

foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    // If type implements/subclasses baseType
    if (baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        // If there is a public parameterless constructor
        if (type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
        {
            IMyInterface obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
        }
    }
}
```